# Meaning of "Evaluation"

Tags: scala, function, methods, evaluation

I am trying to understand the meaning of "evaluation".

I am learning about call by name and call by value in Scala and I am confused about what evaluation means. Is it something that compiler performs to understand my code or is it something like executing/verifying of a method before the actual call to the method ?

I couldn't find a clear explanation except for evaluation strategies.

Could you explain the evaluation for the following example ?

```
 def callByValue(x : Unit) = {
    for (i <- 0 until 5) {
      print(x)
    }
  }

  def callByName(x : => Unit) = {
    for (i <- 0 until 5) {
      print(x)
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/26/call-by-name.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider an even simpler example.

```
def callByValue(x : Unit)   = if (1 > 0) () else x
def callByName(x : => Unit) = if (1 > 0) () else x
```

Notice that `1 > 0` is, of course, always `true` so neither of these methods can ever return the `x` value.

Now let's call them.

```
callByValue(println("Value"))  // res0: Unit = ()
callByName(println("Name"))    // res1: Unit = ()
```

Both calls return `()`, which is the only value of type `Unit`, but the first one, `callByValue()`, has a side effect. It prints the word "Value" to STDOUT. The word "Name" is not printed. Why is that?

It's because the argument passed to `callByValue()` is *evaluated* (i.e. executed) when the method is called. The argument to `callByName()` is not evaluated until that argument, `x`, is referenced, but it is never referenced because the `if` condition is always `true`, the `else` clause is never executed, and `x` is never evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

> .. the meaning of "evaluation" ... Is it something that compiler performs to understand my code or is it something like executing/verifying of a method before the actual call to the method ?

There are many good examples that exemplify the difference between the evaluation strategies, e.g. the one given by @jwvh. There is also a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) article on this subject.

It seems to me that you are confused by the word "evaluation". Perhaps it is easier if you consider an interpreter instead of a compiler. The interpreter is *executing* your program, also known as *evaluating*. For instance Python comes with a builtin function [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) (and also "exec" btw).

"Evaluation strategy" means *when* or *how* the interpreter is going to execute/evaluate the code that will return the actual parameter value.

For a compiled program this is the same except the compiler makes this decision (actually the programmer made it when defining the function) when generating the executable code.